# Perl Net::SSH2 module not working on device list

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am new to Windows Perl and I am trying to use [Net::SSH2](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aSSH2) on [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/). the issue I have the script is unable to connect to device list. I can connect to the first device on the list but unable to connect to 2nd, 3rd so on. did I miss anything. thanks for any suggestion.

```
#!\usr\bin\Perl\bin\perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use NET::SSH2;
use MIME::Base64;

my $host = "C:/temp/devices.txt"; # input file
my $user = "XXX"; # your account
my $pass = "XXXXX"; # your password  64 bit mime
my $ssh2 = Net::SSH2->new();
my $result = "C:/temp/result.txt"; # output file

$ssh2->debug(1); # debug on/off

open(List, '<', "$host") or die "$!";
while(<List>) {
    chomp $_;
    unless ($ssh2->connect("$_")) {
        print "Unable to connect : $_\n";
        next;
    }

    my $dp=decode_base64("$pass");

    unless ($ssh2->auth_password("$user","$dp")) {
        print "Invalid Password\n";
        exit;
    }

    my $chan = $ssh2->channel();
    $chan->exec('sh ver');

    my $buflen =100000;
    my $buf = '0' x $buflen;
    my $read = $chan->read($buf, $buflen );

    warn 'More than ', $buflen, ' characters in listing' if $read >= $buflen;

    open (OUTPUT, '>>', $result) or die "$!";
    print OUTPUT "HOST: $_\n\n";
    print OUTPUT "$buf\n";
    print OUTPUT "\n\n\n";
    print OUTPUT

    $chan->close();
}

close (List);
```

Comment: That should be `use Net:SSH2` not `use NET::SSH2`. It only works because Windows isn't case sensitive.

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: @Brad Gilbert@ I agree on typo error.

Comment: You can completely remove your shebang `#!\usr\bin\Perl\bin\perl`, because 1) its written with backslash, 2) Windows doesn't need it, or use it, 3) the one you are using is a linux path. Your perl path is more likely to be something like `C:/perl/bin/perl.exe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't exit() on an authentication failure; use 'next' to move to the next List item.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I have changed to "next" but still not connecting to the other devices.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the Net::SSH2 object inside the loop because it is not possible to use one Net::SSH2 object to connect to several hosts (or to perform several connections to the same host).

Answer (score 1):

Call **$ssh->disconnect()** after **$chan->close();**

Answer (score 0):

Simply put **my $ssh2 = Net::SSH2->new();** under while loop.

Comment: Please try and provide as much information as possible when answering a question. (e.g.: What would doing this achieve, how would it correct the problem, etc.)

Answer (score -3):

```
   #!\usr\bin\Perl\bin\perl
   use strict;
   use Term::ReadKey;
   use NET::SSH2;
   use MIME::Base64;
   use constant BUFLEN => 10_0000 ;
   my $user = "XXX"; # your account
   my $pass = "XXXX"; # your password  64 bit mime
   my $dp=decode_base64("$pass");
   my $host = "C:/temp/devices.txt"; # input file
   my $Error = "C:/temp/Error.txt"; # Error file
   open(HOST, '<', "$host") or die "$!";
   open STDERR, ">", "$Error"; # open log file
           while(<HOST>) {
              chomp $_;
   my $ssh2 = Net::SSH2->new();
   $ssh2->debug(1); # debug on/off
           unless ($ssh2->connect("$_")) {
           print "Unable to connect : $_\n";
   print STDERR "Unable to connect to $_: $!\n"; # write the error on log file
   print STDERR
   "*****************************************************\n\n";
           next;
           }
        print "connecting to $_\n";
         unless ($ssh2->auth_password("$user","$dp")) {
         print "Invalid Password\n";
         exit;
            }
   my $chan = $ssh2->channel;
         $chan->exec('sh int desc');
              my $buf;
              my $read = $chan->read($buf, BUFLEN );
   warn 'More than ', BUFLEN, ' characters in listing' if $read >= BUFLEN;
   open (OUTPUT, ">", "C:/temp/$_.txt")or die "$!"; # new file for each devices
   print OUTPUT "HOST: $_\n\n";
   print OUTPUT "$buf\n";
   print OUTPUT "\n\n\n";
   print OUTPUT

   $chan->close();
   }
   close HOST;
```

Comment: What solved your issue? Just dumping the code that works and expecting someone to do a diff on it is not acceptable.

Comment: @CanSpice@ I have posted the code because if someone wants to use the code. did I ask any one to find the diff. why you bothered because I have posted working code.

Comment: @Daniel you have to provide the explanation for your answer.First, you have to understand the importance of stack overflow.